# Получение названий населенных мест API Новая Почта

Tags: javascript, новая-почта

На сайте [Новая Почта](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/56248fffa0fe4f0da0550ea8) описан запрос как получить названия городов. Помогите разобраться, что и куда прописывать? Использую JavaScript - код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
                "modelName": "AddressGeneral",
    "calledMethod": "getSettlements",
    "methodProperties": {
        "AreaRef": "dcaadb64-4b33-11e4-ab6d-005056801329",
        "Ref": "0e451e40-4b3a-11e4-ab6d-005056801329",
        "RegionRef": "e4b03a8f-4b33-11e4-ab6d-005056801329",
        "Page": "1",
        "Warehouse": "1"
    },
    "apiKey": "Мой_ключ-3b4674-"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/AddressGeneral/getSettlements/?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: а с чего вы хотите получить их?
Чем вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Использую javaScript код

Comment: а подсказка в самом низу вам не помогла?

Comment: нет, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: покажите код, который вы использовали собственно